# "localStorage is not defined" in Angular

Tags: angular, local-storage

While executing this code, the problem that is popping out is that the "localStorage is not defined".
and also for `todos != Todo[]` why can we not just null it without adding this exclamation mark.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Todo } from "../../Todo";
import { TodoItemsComponent } from "../todo-items/todo-items.component";
import { AddTodoComponent } from '../add-todo/add-todo.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-todo',
    standalone: true,
    templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
    styleUrl: './todo.component.css',
    imports: [CommonModule,TodoComponent, TodoItemsComponent,AddTodoComponent]
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit{
  localItem: string | null;
  todos!: Todo[];

  constructor(){
    this.localItem=localStorage.getItem('todos');
    if(this.localItem == null){ 
      this.todos=[];
    }
    else{
      this.todos=JSON.parse(this.localItem);
    }
    
  }

  deleteTodo(todo:Todo){
    const index=this.todos.indexOf(todo);
    this.todos.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(todo);
    localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(this.todos));
  }
  
  addTodo(todo:Todo){
    this.todos.push(todo);
    console.log(todo);
    localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(this.todos));
  }

 
  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }

  
}
```

[image: Error Description]

Tried to remove the function from constructor and initialize it with ngInit

Answer (score 0):

You're running your app with SSR enabled.

SSR runs on NodeJS but local storage is a browser only API.

You can either:

1. Disable SSR by setting `ssr:false` in `angular.json`
2. wrap the localstorage call wth `afterNextRender()` which runs only CSR.